# Выбрать из таблицы SQL запросом столбец и затем всю таблицу

Tags: sql

Задача такова: вывести запросом `SELECT` столбец `sum` и после него снова всю таблицу. Как это сделать?

Я пробую следующий код:

```
SELECT salary*(1+commission_pct) as "sum", *
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE not commission_pct is null
ORDER BY "sum"
```

Выводится ошибка `SQL Error while processing results: ORA-00936: missing expression`

Столбцы `salary` и `commission_pct` в `EMPLOYEES` присутствуют.

Comment: А вам случайно ограничить наименования столбцов не надо апострофами, а не двойными кавычками!?

Comment: А Вы уверены, что условие вида `WHERE NOT <столбец> IS NULL` — это допустимый синтаксис? Я с диалектом PL/SQL не знаком, но смутные сомнения на этом счет как-то терзают.

Comment: Не уверен, возможно. Однако вот такая вот вещь:

`SELECT salary*(1+commission_pct) as 'sum'
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE not commission_pct is null
ORDER BY 'sum'`

выдаёт ошибку `SQL Error while processing results: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: С where всё норм, это допустимый синтаксис.

Comment: И все-таки, чисто для очистки совести, попробуйте записать его в соответствующем стандарту (да и [документации](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/isnotnull.php)) виде: `WHERE <столбец> IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Хорошо, я так сделаю, однако для очистки своей совести скажу что я в SQL полный нуб и этот синтаксис взял отсюда: http://sql.az/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=67&Itemid=101&lang=ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так напишите:

```
SELECT salary*(1+commission_pct) as "sum", EMPLOYEES.*
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE not commission_pct is null
ORDER BY "sum"
```